# How to solve this Javascript error TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 't.subscribe')?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, poltergeist

Following error occur when I am clicking on one item to open on web.Can anyone of us know solution?

> Error:
>   test_inline_edit_an_item_app_built_via_app_builder(TaskFeature):
>   Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError: One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

---

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 't.subscribe')
>   at https://d3tga9h80dykic.cloudfront.net/assets/cd319648/podio-common-amd.js:1
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/poltergeist-1.1.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:197:in command'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/poltergeist-1.1.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:42:infind'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/poltergeist-1.1.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:110:in find'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:113:inblock in all'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:78:in synchronize'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:112:inall'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:26:in block in find'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:78:insynchronize'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:26:in find'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:341:inblock (2 levels) in class:Session'
>   /home/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in block (2 levels) in '
>   task_feature.rb:489:inblock in test_inline_edit_an_item_app_built_via_app_builder'
>   /home/abhay/podio/auto_deetee/auto_deetee/test/test_helper.rb:69:in login_as'
>   task_feature.rb:473:intest_inline_edit_an_item_app_built_via_app_builder'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Comment: You haven't provided enough information here for people to easily help you. Is this your own application you are clicking? If yes, then you need to show people some relevant code. If no, then I'm afraid this is not a place you go to for general help with any random problem you may experience on the internet.

Comment: Sir actually I mentioned this is not occuring due to code & when no code error.which code I would show you?And can you ask me in which point you want information in detail?

Comment: The address of the web page where you clicked the item would be a good start - but, as I have mentioned already, StackOverflow is not a general helpdesk site for any problems with random sites on the internet.

Comment: I know and I do not want personal help friend.I want to more focus on 
1. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 't.subscribe')
2. Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError
Its on ant URL I am using my mail's url(Gmail)
I'm not getting why that error occurs?It stands for what?How to solve?

Comment: Not a ROR guy myself, but the general message here is that `t.subscribe` has not been defined anywhere, but the code is expecting to treat it as an object, and is perhaps trying to read one of its properties, or similar.

Comment: Yes correct.Now you are getting me.But in that case,I did not use/define subscribe anywhere in code.Its a error of Poltergeist,correct? so how I can overcome it?

Comment: I've retagged your question and added poltergiest - hopefully someone with relevant expertise will help, but I think you are going to have to post up more details about what actions you are performing that generate this error, and and where you perform them. Good Luck!

Comment: can you provide me link where you retagged my question? Thanks.:)

Comment: you can retag by editing your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error happens when Poltergeist detects Javascript errors on the page you are testing. Poltergeist does this to ensure that you have error-free Javascript code on your site (which is what most people want).

However, some people don't want to be notified of Javascript errors. Therefore, you can use [the `js_errors: false` option](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#customization) to make this error go away. (That won't fix your Javascript though.)

Comment: @vint-i-vuit Accepted !